# Select an item in Datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a quite some experience with DataGridViews, I cannot resolve this super simple issue...

I have a datagridview with a comboboxcolumn **pre-set** possible options (3 simple options). I have a database with table, form which I want to select the correct value for the cell in the column. I need to preserve the option for that the user might change the option later (and save it back to DB).

I created a datatable with options:

```
    Dim dtShift As New DataTable
    dtShift.Columns.Add("ValueM")
    dtShift.Columns.Add("DisplayM")
    dtShift.Rows.Add({123, "123"})
    dtShift.Rows.Add({345, "345"})
    dtShift.Rows.Add({678, "678"})
```

Then I assign the values this way (ds is dataset filled with data):

```
    Me.DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Dim colpon As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = Me.DataGridView1.Columns("PonLen")
    With colpon
        .DataSource = dtShift
        .ValueMember = "ValueM"
        .DisplayMember = "DisplayM"
        .DataPropertyName = "PonLen".ToString   ' contains an option like "345"
        '.ValueMember = "PonLen"    ' not needed, if Display member is saved 
    End With
```

...but this doesn't work well, even though it is as close as I could get. I 
The columns have **correct options**, there are **correct values selected**, but DataErrorEvent floods a test-log TextBox with **errors** like this:

```
Row=12 cell=3 : System.FormatException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
```

Comment: What is the type of column `PonLen`? Make sure that type that column is same as type of `ValueM` column in the option DataTable

Comment: PonLen is TinyInt. I'll see how I can specify data type for the datatable columns.

Comment: I specified data type of the value member:  dtShift.Columns(0).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32") - but it didn't help to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem was in the data types, I didn't realized, that a differences like System.Int16 vs System.Byte (ShortInt vs tinyInt) does matter.

DB field: **TinyInt** (0 to 256)

ValueMember: System.**Byte** (0 to 256 - changed from System.Int16 or 32)

...and now it works - the same way as it did, but throws no errors :-)

Regards,

Oak